# How can I get rid of this context menu option?

Tags: macos, shortcut-menu

I deleted AppDelete from my computer because I used it once and it sat on my computer for like forever. Now every time I click on something in finder, it gives me the option to delete it with AppDelete. How can I get rid of this?

[image: annoying AppDelete option]

You can see it is the bottom option in the popup menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From: http://www.reggieashworth.com/appdelete

> AppDelete keeps a .workflow file to provide a contextual menu item for convenience. If ever removal is required simply delete it from your /Library/Services folder. Or on Leopard your /Library/Workflows/Applications/Finder folder.

It appears you should be able to remove that menu item by deleting an item from one of the afore mentioned folders depending on which OS you have installed.

Comment: i have lion running on my macbook pro, i can't find the Services folder inside of Library

Comment: Probably because you're looking in the wrong `Library`. The Library you're looking for is not visible by default, try this link => http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/04/show-library-directory-in-mac-os-x-lion/